# Face in the arm in Tahnanun- when did it start?

Tags: history, tachanun, provenance

What are the arguments against putting the face in the arm in Tahahnun? When did this Minhag start?

Comment: What makes you think there are arguments against this custom?

Comment: @Dave I think I've heard that there are in the name of Arizal.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5413/759

Comment: Maybe the "when did this minhag start" aspect could be emphasized in order to avoid the duplication.

Comment: well sephardim do not have the practice

Comment: @simchashatorah not according to my siddur quoting the Hida and a few other Aharonim I believe (Siddur Od Avinu Hai).

Comment: really i thought the reason for mot doing it is the CHIDA

Comment: @simchashatorah I heard in the name of the Ari, but I don't remember seeing it when he discusses Tahahnun (Shaar Hakavanot pg. 52 I believe).

Comment: Hacham Gabriel, when you ask "When did this Minhag start?", are you referring to one's putting his face in his arm, or are you referring to one's not putting his face in his arm?

Comment: The first question, "What are the arguments against putting the face in the arm in Tahahnun?", is a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5413. The second question, "When did this Minhag start?", is unclear (please see my previous comment). I'm closing this temporarily so the question can be clarified and distinguished form the other, and will then be glad to reopen it (please ping me by use of `@msh210`).