# Sepharadic Tachanun

Tags: tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tachanun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not falling on hands for Tachnun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/not-falling-on-hands-for-tachnun)

How come Sepharadim do not "fall on their faces" during Tachanun as Ashkenazim do, if the prayer is called "nefilat apa'im" (literally *the falling of the faces*)?

The Shulchan Aruch seems to hold of the practice of literally putting one's face down in [O"C 131:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=21)