# The Origins of the Zohar - Why is it accepted as being true?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, mesorah-tradition, authorship, zohar

I've read arguments and counter arguments for the origins of the *Zohar* and I'm perplexed.

I personally accept the truths in *kabbalah* and *chassidut*, but I didn't realize how the *Zohar* sort of just "appeared" one day in 13th/14th century. *Le-havdil*, this sounds like how other religions start; with one man claiming to have found an ancient text he won't let anyone else see.

For sure, there are traditional arguments - and even secular academic ones - that paint a better picture of events and present other possibilities for the provenance of the texts of the *Zohar*.

My question is: With such a shaky story, do we say that *Zohar* is accepted based on the truth it contains (i.e. regardless of where it is actually stems from) rather than the *mesorah* (since it apparently doesn't have one)?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36988 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34269

Comment: I find it both fascinating and perplexing that no one seems to have even some degree of understanding of why the great Torah scholars who originally accepted the Zohar? The implications of there being no valid (or even semi-valid) הוא אמינא for so many great Rabbis/Torah scholars are so great that it should make every G-d fearing Jew shudder at the thought. A glance at the pro-Zohar answers to this post should be enought to show anyone just how difficult this problem is, with big names, like the Arizal and the Vilna Gaon. What are we supposed to think about all of this?

Comment: It seems to me that two separate questions are mixed up, both in the OP and in the answers. 1) Origins of the Zohar? 2) Why is it accepted as being true? These are two separate questions. The second one is the really important one. I'm guessing that gedolim studied it afterwards and thought it was incredibly valuable, augmenting their grasp of Torah in a profound way. They could see that the author was their master and that his teachings fit with their Torah and added to it. - This is _unlike_, say, the fake Yerushalmi, where the only value it had was if it was real.

Comment: The Kuzari, by the way, is another example. I don't think anyone _cares_ if the incident with the King and the Sage actually happened. The sefer is full of valuable Torah insights from a Rishon.

Comment: I guess I'm really just coming down on one of the two sides in the OP's question: "Zohar is accepted based on the truth it contains (i.e. regardless of where it actually stems from)"

Comment: A point _against_ what I commented here: Later poskim often quote the Zohar as a very high-authority text. For instance, the Magen Avraham (?) suggests that the Rosh would perhaps not have held that you should put on tefillin on Chol Hamoed if he had seen the Zohar that opposes it. That doesn't make any sense if the Zohar was an (incredibly insightful) sefer from roughly the same time. It would not outrank the Rosh.

Answer (score 8):

According to the *haqdamah* of the *Mishneh Torah*, it seems that any book(s) or commentary(s) which may have arisen after the *hhatimath ha-talmudh* ("the sealing of the *Talmudh*") - such as the writings of the *geonim* or even the Rambam's own book - are measured by their faithfulness to the halakhic and aggadic literature bequeathed to us by *Hazal* and their students (i.e. *Mishnah*, *Tosefta*, *Mekhiltoth*, *Sifra*, *Sifre*, *Bavli*, *Yerushalmi*, and the Tannaitic *midrashim*/*baraytoth*). Much like the prophets were tested against the collective *mesorah* up until their time, and by abrogation of it they themselves were rejected, so also are books composed since the close of the Talmudic age in need of such "testing."

Now, granted that there are two types of potential errors in such books:

1. **Unintentional errors of interpretation or logical understanding, etc.** - In other words, a certain *talmidh hakhamim* codifies the *halakhah* as he sees it and explains *hashqafah* as he understands it from *Tanakh* and *Hazal*, but perhaps the *halakhah* is not like him and perhaps he misunderstands such issues as the nature of suffering or the function of *sekhar wa-`onesh* (or similar issues). These types of potential "mistakes" do not necessarily disqualify the author, rather we see that to attempt to understand Torah is a process where have to accept that different views of Torah from the sources is not only possible but probable.
2. **Departures from *mesorah* or attempts to replace it/abrogate it** - Should a new book or treatise be written that stands in opposition to the *halakhah* or *hashqafah* as expressed by *Tanakh* and *Hazal* - especially that which seeks not to understand but to supplant - is to be rejected. Examples are "new revelations" that, rather than seek to understand the statements of *Hazal* in aggregate, attempt to make the case for "secret teachings" or "hidden meanings" that are in contradiction to established *mesorah* - such books and their authors are to be rejected.

[**NOTE**: I am aware that the above are fairly general and that it could be discussed in more detail, such as when to set aside *midrashim* in favor of *peshat* or outdated "scientific" ideas in order to incorporate new ones. However, for now these definitions should suffice for this answer.]

Certainly each of the above has limitations. For example, and perhaps most importantly, there are ideas about which different views are not acceptable and cannot be tolerated, such as the nature of the *yihhudh* *HaShem*, or the fact of a physical, bodily resurrection, or the permanence and immutability of the Torah. Such things (and those like them) define *apiqorsim* and *minim* (cf. *Hilkhoth Teshuvah* 3:14-17f) , and the Rambam - drawing on the text of the *Mishnah* and logical monotheism - composed his 13 Foundations of Jewish faith to show us where our speculation may go before it is undone and where we are not allowed to budge in our basic religious ideas and ideals.

Many books have come on the scene - both pre-Talmudic and post - claiming to be authentic to our *mesorah*, or to extend it, or to replace it. Examples include the "New Testament," the "*Qur'aan*," the "Kebra Nagast," the books of the Shabbateans (followers of Shabbetai Tzvi, *yimahh shemo wa-zikhro*, and many others. Many of them were accepted by great people. If *Shelomoh HaMelekh* could worship idols, if *Elisha` ben Avuyah* ("*Ahher*") could accept the idea of *ribbui reshayoth* from the books of the dualists, if Yohhanan Kohen Gadhol could become a *Ssaduqi* at the end of his life, if the Hakham Ssvi z"l could accept Shabbetai Tzvi (*yimahh shemo*) as the *mashiyyahh*, and if the Hafess Hhayyim z"l could be led to accept the blatantly forged (supposedly lost) *Seder Qodhashin* of the *Talmudh Yerushalmi* (and even changing his halakhic practices based on the forgery), then the fact that the *Zohar* was accepted by many great scholars when it first published should neither surprise us nor become the sure basis for its acceptance.

As an aside, one of the most common misconceptions is the equating of *qabbalah* with the *Zohar* literature; if the latter is rejected, it is thought, then the former ceases to exist. Such an idea is patently false, but nevertheless demonstrates how entrenched in the minds of contemporary Judaism is the idea that all authentic spirituality or "mysticism" in Judaism is inextricably linked to the ideas expressed in the *Zohar*. The fact is that the bodies of knowledge known as *ma'aseh merqavah* ("Workings of the Chariot" - i.e. metaphysics) and *ma'aseh bereshith* ("Workings of the Creation" - i.e. physics) - as mentioned in the *Mishnah*, *masekhet Hhaghighah* - preceded the 13th century publication of the *Zohar* by [possibly] thousands of years, as did the *Sefer Yessirah*. The *Sefer Yessirah* is referred to and expounded by the *Kuzari* and Sa'adyah Gaon, among others. The Rambam himself makes veiled references to these ideas in his *Moreh HaNevokhim*, expounding (where possible) mystical and philosophical concepts related to both *ma'aseh bereshith* and *ma'aseh merqavah*.

But this leads to another fact that is often overlooked in the history of the *Zohar* - many qabbalists at the time of its publication (and afterward) ***rejected it as being authentic***. Rabbi Avraham Zacuto, in his *Sefer HaYuhhasin*, relates the extant portion of an account written by the well-known qabbalist Rabbi Yisshhaq De-Akko (a *talmidh* of the Ramban) who traveled to the home of Mosheh De Leon and offered to purchase the original manuscripts of the *Zohar* from his widow, whereupon she confessed to him that there were no original manuscripts and that her late husband had forged it and attributed it to Shimon ben Yohhai in an effort to gain acclaim and a higher purchase price. Other well-known qabbalists who rejected the *Zohar* as an authentic book of *mesorah* were Rabbi Ya'aqov Emden and the *Hhathem Sofer* (who was the student of the famed and intense mystic, Rabbi Nathan Adler). Their use of language is strong against the *Zohar*, using words like "forgery" and "lies" to describe it. All the while, however, these men and others maintained a highly-developed mystical system based on earlier literature.

The facts are clear to all who are willing to take an honest look: the *Zohar* contradicts a great many things which came before it in both the realm of *halakhah* and *hashqafah* - even surround such things as are "off limits" such as the nature of the *yihhudh HaShem*. And these things are well-known, they are not my invention nor the invention of secular scholars seeking to defame religion. They have been discussed and wrestled with for hundreds of years by rabbis and scholars in every area of Jewish literature. It has been proven that the Zohar borrows and incorporates sections of Rashi, *Tosafoth*, the Rambam, and other works which preceded it. It also contains a vast amount of original material, much of which is controversial when compared to works containing established *mesorah* from *Hazal*. This being the case, it is true that there are genuinely positive statements and spiritual truths expressed in the *Zohar*, however it is also true that there are severe statements of polytheism and dualism expressed there as well. So, the operating principle (it seems) is that anything good in the *Zohar* may already be found in uncontested and authentic works that preceded it, and anything questionable is of it's own invention. Such an observation makes the *Zohar* superfluous and the attempt to incorporate it into the corpus of Jewish literature as being more trouble that it is worth. The continuous heretical movements which base themselves upon it (e.g. the Shabbateans) and the seemingly endless stream of charlatans offering miracle cures, instant wealth, and superpowers of protection to those who embrace the Zoharic qabbalistic system are a proof that giving *Zohar* a prime place in Judaism has proven almost disastrous. The fact is that much of the good brought by *hasidism* could have been brought without the aid of Zoharic literature.

The historical Jewish response to the *Zohar* can be divided into three basic approaches:

1. **Full acceptance** - The full acceptance of the *Zohar* and its attendant literature as being 100% authentic is most aptly characterized by the Hasidic movement(s) and the North African *Sefaradim*. These adherents hold it as the holiest text in Judaism and should be used to "correct" all other texts - especially those which came before it - which are viewed as being "ignorant" or "unaware" of the secret tradition that it holds.
2. **Modified acceptance** - This approach, most commonly associated with the Gr"a and his *talmidhim*, is to effectively accept the Zohar, but to reject its commentaries. In other words, the Gr"a took great liberties to "re-read" the text of the *Zohar* in order to make it fit into the established *mesorah*. By doing so, he rejected many of the ideas of Lurianic *qabbalah*, and sought new readings (many of which are either based on his own emendations of the text or forced readings of the plain meaning of the Aramaic) to remove conflict and controversy. However, in doing so, the Gr"a also "re-reads" the text of the *gemara* in certain places and in some cases reverses generations of clear and uncontested *pesaq halakhah* from the *gemara* to accommodate the clear ruling of the *Zohar* to the contrary (one example of this is the wearing of *tefillin* on *Hholo shel mo'edh*).
3. **Full rejection** - Characterized most aptly by the 19th-century *Dor De'ah* movement in Yemen led by Rav Yihhyah Qafihh z"l. Rav Qafihh authored a book entitled *Milhhamoth HaShem* ("The Wars of HaShem") wherein he effectively demonstrates (like other *hakhamim* before him) that the Zohar simply cannot be a product of *Hazal* and their students, is subsequently not an authentic work of *mesorah*, and therefore must be rejected. This and other groups rely instead on the works of previous and established authors for spirituality, such as the Rambam (*Moreh HaNevokhim*), Rabbi Yehudhah HaLewi (*Kuzari*), Rabbi Bahhyah ibn Pequdha (*Hhovoth HaLevavoth*), Sa'adyah Gaon (*Pirush 'al Sefer HaYessirah* and *HaNivhhar Emunoth Wa-De'oth*), and others.

We have a principle of "*lo ba-shamayim hi*", i.e. that the Torah is not "in heaven" and therefore we do not base our belief in any certain book or teacher based on purported "miracles" or claims of special "revelation" or "prophecy." Instead, we are charged with being faithful to the texts and the *mesorah* that we have to judge all that comes after it. This is why the latter two approaches (i.e. any approach beyond blind acceptance) take measures to study the relevant sources in order to formulate their opinions, rather than seeking a sign or relying on the fact that the likes of the Arizal gave it their approbation.

To answer your question directly, the *Zohar* has been accepted - and continues to be so - based on "mob rule" so to speak. In other words, since it has been read and used by a lot of Jews for a long time, we assume that it is true. In reality, however, there is no basis for its acceptance, but rather to the contrary. And as has been shown, there is nothing on the part of its supporters to substantiate their claims other than dogmas and the attribution of "special powers" or "revelations" or mystical "prophecy" on the part of those famed historical figures who did accept it, while attributing error and arrogance to those scholars who argued against it. It is exactly as you said, it is no different than the many false religious movements that have arisen in world history; they begin with charismatic and bold claims based essentially on nothing and demand blind obedience from all with whom they speak. But in the end, their claims are empty and their reasoning is circular.

Have you ever wondered why those who merely question the authenticity of the *Zohar* are threatened with excommunication and charges of heresy, while those who propose that a section of the *gemara* should be emended (and other such normal acts of Torah scholarship) are met with none of these? *Le-`aniyuth Da'ati*, it seems that those without truly substantive arguments have nothing left but threats of Divine judgment and *ad hominem* attacks. Sound familiar?

And **PLEASE** do not take my word for it - go and see for yourself. Investigate the matter thoroughly and with an open mind. If you come thereby to another conclusion, then you will have no threats and suffer no humiliation from me. And I certainly will not threaten you with a charge of "arrogance" for not seeing things the way that this or that scholar has.

I hope that this helps. Kol tuv.

Comment: But why did the "mob" _start_ reading it and using it?

Comment: I don't know. Why did the "mob" worship Baal in the time of Yermiyahu or accept Shabbetai Tzvi (*yimahh shemo*) or do anything that the "mob" does? It's why the same *pasuq* from which we derive the necessity to follow a majority rule in *beth din* also tells us that we are forbidden from following the crowd to commit evil, I.e. just because alot of people do something doesn't make it right. But you know this already, so what are you really asking? Kol tuv.

Comment: He's asking because he wants you to answer the question, if I know @DoubleAA at all! The question asked "With such a shaky story, do we say that Zohar is accepted based on the truth it contains (i.e. regardless of where it is actually stems from) rather than the mesorah (since it apparently doesn't have one)? " Did you answer that?

Comment: The Chochom Tzvi was not a Sabbatean, just for the record. He and his son both were strong opponents of that movement and entered into machloket with followers of Shabbatai Sbi who were accepted within their communities.

Comment: Ha. Read further. The Hakham Ssvi initially accepted the yimah shemo and only realized his error later when he became a virulent opponent of the false messiah. But, yes, he and his sons became strong opponents of the Sabbatean movement. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist source for the claim in your previous comment?

Comment: "any book(s) or commentary(s) which may have arisen after the hhatimath ha-talmudh are measured by their faithfulness to the halakhic and aggadic literature bequeathed to us by Hazal". I think this is the important point you made, and it contradicts everything else you said. According to the gedolim who accepted the Zohar, they felt that it was more than faithful, it was an incredible addition to their understanding. That you don't agree with them is irrelevant.

Comment: @user3342 I don't see why you would call the Chacham Tzvi a Sabbatean, then. That sounds like calling Rabbi Akiva a Bar Kochba-an: He supported him when his true nature was not clear, then called him out when it was. It sounds like the Chacham Tzvi was the same.

Answer (score 4):

Another point mentioned by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan [here](http://www.simpletoremember.com/faqs/Kaplan-SimpleToRemember.com.pdf):

> Around three years ago, someone came to me and
>   asked me to translate parts of a manuscript of Rabbi
>   Yitzchok deMin Acco, known as Otzar HaChaim. There is
>   only one complete copy of this manuscript in the world, and
>   this is in the Guenzberg Collection in the Lenin Library in
>   Moscow. This person got me a complete photocopy of the
>   manuscript and asked me to translate certain sections. I
>   stated that the only condition I would translate the
>   manuscript is if I get to keep the copy. This is how I got my
>   hands on this very rare and important manuscript.
>
> Of course, like every other sefer in my house, it had to be read. It
>   took a while to decipher the handwriting, since it is an ancient
>   script. One of the first things I discovered was that it was written
>   some 20 years after Rabbi Yitzchok investigated the Zohar. He openly,
>   and clearly and unambiguously states that the Zohar was written by
>   Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai. This is something not known to historians,
>   and this is the first time I am discussing it in a public forum. But
>   the fact is that the one person who is historically known to have
>   investigated the authenticity of the Zohar at the time it was first
>   published, unambiguously came to the conclusion that it  was an
>   ancient work written by Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai.

He writes in the footnote

> One can view this manuscript today on micro film at YU or Brandeis
>   University
>   (http://library.brandeis.edu/specialcollections/collections/mancoll3.html).

However the link no longer works.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Are you suggesting that people accepted it because of his research, and then we all lost the research? Do you have any evidence of this?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes. People accepted it because of his research and once it was accepted there was no need to continue to prove it.

Comment: But you are just making this theory up. Why should we believe you? You haven't provided any evidence for your claim

Comment: @DoubleAA I think every theory has to be made up. The evidence is in the post above and the fact that this research is not known today.

Comment: Every theory is made up. The question is, how much do I trust the person making it up to know his stuff, and how compelling is his argumentation and evidence. You have 0 credibility with me, and you have 0 evidence (there is no evidence in the post above for the claim that the Zohar's acceptance was due to RYdMA's research, nor is the fact that RYdMA's research is not commonly known today (if that's even true) evidence of anything). So why do you expect anyone to value this post?

Comment: There is evidence, the  link is probably too old and is not working anymore. That doesn't mean the evidence doesn't exist, it just means its needs to be re-found. I was actually hoping that someone might know how to find the new link as I tried and was unsuccessful. I don't expect everyone to value this post, but I do expect that those that value Rabbi Kaplan's research will find value in it.

Comment: I think you are confused. Even if the link says what R Kaplan says it says, that is not evidence that RYdMA is the reason it became accepted. It just implies that for some reason RYdMA accepted it (or that he didn't mind pseudepigraphical attributions).

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't intend for my response to be taken alone, which is why it was prefaced with "Another point". I believe the conclusion of the main investigator is more inline with the result of the Zohar's acceptance.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What main investigation? The question wasn't about if the Zohar was accepted (by those who accept it). You seem confused about what you are trying to say and how it answers the question. This is not just a place to post any information about the Zohar.

Answer (score 2):

See Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan's Inner Space chapter 1 (through page 7) along with footnotes. His basic argument is that all of Jewish mysticism (works like Sefer Yetzeira, Bahir, Heichalot material, Zohar, etc.) were transmitted to Moshe at Sinai and were orally transmitted after that. Throughout the time of prophecy this knowledge was guarded and only really accessible to those who had attained prophecy (note: as indicated in Tanach, there were schools of prophecy and there were many thousands who achieved this spiritual level, only prophecy which was relevant to all generations was recorded for posterity). After the destruction of the temple and the cessation of prophecy these oral traditions were in danger of being forgotten. Various "schools" coalesced around spiritual giants such as Rabbi Akiva (who transmitted the secrets of the Merkava) and Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai who transmitted (orally) the main material of the Zohar. These transmissions were an amalgamation of oral tradition and divine or semi-prophetic revelation (via the prophet Elijah). Over time in order that this wisdom not be forgotten students began to write it down. The compilation of several such works became canonized as the Zohar.

He also refers to Rabbi David Luria's Kadmut Sefer HaZohar 5:2. In footnote 30 he states:

> ...In the case of Rabbi Shimon's school, the Zohar consisted of volumes of notes in manuscript form which were hidden away in a vault and not uncovered until the 13th century. After limited circulation in the 1270's and 1280's, these notes came into the hands of R. Moshe de Leon (1238-1305) who finally edited and published them in the 1290's...

So, to answer your question in short, the material in question was not deemed appropriate for public consumption and was therefore transmitted orally to only select individuals for many hundreds of years (Judaism is not the only example of this type of secret oral transmission). It was finally gathered and published at the end of the 13th century but certainly didn't simply pop up out of nowhere. If it had (I'm editorializing here, Rabbi Kaplan does not say this) I cannot imagine it gaining such immediate and widespread acceptance.

Comment: I would appreciate if downvoters could leave a comment explaining what they feel is lacking in the answer. This would help me improve it.

Comment: You don't explain why the Zohar was accepted as being true, you just asset that it is. Somebody published it and said it had been in a vault for a millennium. Why did anyone believe that? Would you believe me if I said that about something I found today (but wouldn't show you the original of)? Maybe that's what's lacking in this answer

Comment: @DoubleAA the question as I understood it was is the Zohar accepted based on its content since it doesn't have any mesorah. My answer disputes that supposition by outlining said mesorah

Comment: Then you deserve downvotes for supporting a false statement. There is no evidence of such a Mesorah. Anyone can claim that there was a secret tradition that no one knew about. Thats not a Mesorah as far as the question is concerned. What if I today said I was the recipient of a secret Mesorah of 4000 years that Moshe was really a girl, and only now I decided to make it public. Would anyone care? If I would be accepted, it wouldnt be due to claiming without any evidence an ancient Mesorah. For 99.9% of Jews in the Middle Ages including many Rishonim, there was no known Msorah. So why belive it?

Comment: I don't even know what Mesorah you think there was. Are you saying that the secret mesorah (so secret most rishonim didn't know of it and no one ever hinted at it) was that there was a document hidden in a secret vault authored by Rashbi for 1500 years with such-and-such content? That seems absurd. Even if there was a Mesorah from Moshe about the Sefirot or whatever, why would anyone believe the Zohar was real? Did they know where the vault was? Did they know why it was put in a vault? How did it stay safe in the vault? So how does this answer the question?

Comment: @DoubleAA orthodox Judaism is based on oral tradition. There are references to secretive texts such as the sefer yetzeira or special names of God such as the 42 letter name scattered throughout the talmud, not to mention the discussion of the 4 who entered Pardes. Scholars date heichalot material to around the time of the temple. Raavad III, Ramban and other Rishonim reference esoteric teachings that were not put down as text. 

So I am quoting Rabbi Kaplan, a respected figure, as saying there was a secret mesorah that was orally passed down until some of it was compiled into the zohar

Comment: Most of what you just said is irrelevant; I don't know why you said it. You seem to be mixing up a few stories here. You can't at the same time hold that the Zohar was found in a vault and that it was passed down orally until being written down by various students in the 13th century. Also, claiming that there were secret traditions is different from claiming this is that tradition. You have no evidence for the latter claim. To see that note I can still claim that along with the secret tradition of Kabbalah there was a secret tradition that Moshe was a girl, and I'm only now revealing it etc.

Comment: So when someone came along and said "this is the secret tradition", why did anyone believe him? Was it because of a Mesorah or because of its contents? Clearly many people were not in on this secret tradition (R Saadya Gaon, Rambam, etc.)

Comment: @DoubleAA not sure what you're not getting here. Rabbi Kaplan is stating that there was a mesorah. His claim is credible based on the fact that there is evidence of esoteric wisdom being passed down orally. Rabbi Kaplan further cites a source regarding manuscripts. True, there are early authorities who may not have subscribed to the validity of these teachings but that doesn't disprove their existence. The OP questioned the mesorah of the Zohar. I cited a credible source stating that it has one. You may disagree with the source, but that doesn't warrant a downvote if you can't disprove it.

Comment: A source stating it has no Mesorah is equally credible (so credibility is clearly not relevant here). The fact that someone from long after it was published provides a logically consistent claim is not a basis for believing anything. Why do you mention the vault in your answer if you don't seem to believe that story? What Mesorah are you claiming there was? We've just gone around in a circle where all you've said is R Kaplan is not logically inconsistent and that there is minor evidence of secret traditions in Judaism. Why did you bother telling me that here? Go back and try responding again.

Answer (score -1):

the zohar was overwhelmingly backed by great torah scholars who quote it in their works such as

Rav Yosef Karo

the Arizal

the Ramchal

Baal HaTanya

Vilna Gaon

Ben Ish Chai

Leshem

Chafetz Chaim

all of whom quote it in their books.

the list goes on and on. those who did not back it are a tiny minority in comparison and it is doubtful they would still say so today given all who backed it over time.

as to how all these great men knew, it is not up for us to judge. "God shares His secrets with those who fear Him" (Tehillim 25:14)

Comment: Besides for some other problems with this answer, most importantly, it does not answer the question of why the Zohar was accepted so broadly. It just claims that the Zohar was accepted very broadly. The question is why. Consider revising.

Comment: If that is the basis for your answer then edit it in (expect downvotes because that argument has already been presented on this page and been dealt with extensively.)

Comment: How do you reconcile your Catholic-esque implications of rabbinic infallibility with your acknowledgement that rabbis stood on both sides of the issue? Or with massekhet Horayot?

Comment: Source for Rav Yosef Karo please

Comment: @ShmuelBrin http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4065-caro-joseph-b-ephraim

Comment: @ShmuelBrin and another http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5456/2960

Answer (score -1):

Per R' Meir ibn Gabbai it didn't just "appear" in the 13/14th century but was composed by the Tannaim and transmitted. Does this constitute "mesorah" per your question?

Avodat haKodesh, 3:17 (towards the middle/end):
https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Avodat_Hakodesh/3#17

...
And in the second essay, second Shaar of his book he [Rambam?] turned this holy essay to the rubbish of the roots of the Greek [philosopher] and his "visions," and explained it like this and wants to say: Why when the Shunamite woman (2 Kings 4) was given her good tidings that Elisha bid her giving her a son at the designated time, and the vision was confounded afterwards, that the tiding was given to the woman and not to her husband, that this proves that that prophecy was from the side of Dimyon (fantasy) which is female in relation to Sekhel (intellect), bla bla. But Avraham Avinu, for whom his prophecy and tidings were not confounded etc. - Behold! Because he thinks there is nothing that can't be weighed by rational intellect from whatever comes from Chazal's words, he filled his heart to explain it in such a way. Now, what's impossible for the intellect to reckon and see, and furthermore he was wise in every thing, "no hint escaping him" - and if he'd have "just kept quiet he'd have been considered wise" (Prov. 17:28) - so now removing the stumblingblock let me tell the traditional (m'kubal) explanation in the holy meanings A"H (??) in this essay:

Namely, for it's known to the wise of heart that the lower female is from the upper female, the secret of the final H' in in the name of Ha-Kallah (the bride) in Shir haShirim, and it's tied to it, since the Neshama of the female is from the female, as stated in the Bahir. And the lower male is from the upper male, the secret of WA"W in the Name, and is tied to it, since the male Neshama is from the male as they said there. And since the "legs" of that female Midah "go down to death" (Prov. 5:5) as is known to the Mekablei haEmet, behold whoever binds to her alone, death is ready for him, for the Midah is goremet/influencing, and since HaBaKuk [the Shunamite woman's child, Zohar I:8b] was bound to the female (aspect), as the prophet told her (2 Kings 4:16), "you are embracing (at HoBeKet) a son" - so he died, until the Ruach Chayyim was activated upon him from Above, as it's written, "And he placed his mouth on his mouth" etc., and they said there in the Midrash, "To reconnect him to a different place supernal, the place where Life is located" etc., and then his Ruach returned to him.

And since Yitzchak was bound to the male (aspect), the place of The Life, as it's written, Shuv-ashuv eleikha (Gen. 18:10, and see Rashi who in addition brings B"R there contrasting with Habakkuk) so he endured. This demonstrates the truth. For one may not measure by intellectual reasoning, any thing that comes closed in that book or any other book he mentions, for philosophy has no part or memory in them, for behold he admits they are not encompassed by the intellect of any philosopher or wisdom/science of those books. **It is what our Rabbis z"l received and knew, and the philosophy did not, for behold the Sefer Heikhalot, Pirkei haHeikhalot, Sefer Shiur Qomah, and Sefer haZohar - the Tannaim taught them and composed them - and Sefer haBahir is composed by the Amoraim, and besides these there are many, the compositions of the Geonim and those that came after them, and the Chakhamim have them all, and these Sefarim were never copied and never went out from our people to another people, for behold Sefer Yetzirah since the time of Avraham Avinu is found among his Holy People, and Yirmiyahu a"h since the time of the First Temple was engaged with it, as we find in Sefer haBitachon by R' Yehudah ben Batirah a"h, he brings Rav Chamai Gaon z"l in Sefer haYichud, and also the holy Kanah zlh"h in Sefer haPeliah, saying there that Yirmiyahu haNavi a"h was engaged in Sefer Yetzira by himself; a Bat Kol emerged and said, K'neh l'kha chaver, acquire for yourself a friend; he went to Sira his son and they were engaged in Sefer Yetzirah three years, to fulfill the scripture "Then will be spoken to, those that fear H', man to his fellow" etc. And he [Rambam] already admits and does not shy away from this and he mentioned them, and from those that exist from the time of the Second Temple and did not go out in the Exile and were not emptied out from the holy, pure vessel to a secular and impure vessel and not copied and not lost among the nations, and in every single generation the remaining Chakhamim engage in them and explain their secrets as they received them — so how could his heart devise, he and his Rav, when he said that the great Chokhmot found in our people and the books the Chakhamim composed about the roots of that Chokhmah were lost?! This is nothing from them but donkey calling and predisposition in order to establish their fantasized opinions according the rational/scientific intellect in them, weakening the hands of the pure and innocent that seek the Truth.**
...

```
ובמאמר השני שער שני מספרו הפך זה המאמר המקודש לתפלות שרשי היוני והזיותיו, ופירשו כך וירצה כי למה שבשורת השונמית אשר בשר אותה אלישע לתת לה בן למועד האמור, נתערב בה הדמיון אחרי אשר נתנה הבשורה לאשה ולא לבעלה אשר זהו מורה היות אותה הנבואה מצד הדמיון אשר היא נקבה בערך לשכל וכו', אמנם באברהם אבינו אשר לא נתערב בנבואתו ובשורתו וכו' הנה כי להיותו חושב שאין דבר שלא ישוקל בשקל השכל ממה שבא בדבריהם ז"ל, מלאו לבו לפרש כן מה שאי איפשר אל השכל להולמו ולהראות עוד שהוא מתחכם בכל וכל רז לא אנס ליה ואלו החריש חכם יחשב, ולהרים מכשול אומר הפירוש המקובל בכוונת הקדוש ע"ה בזה המאמר:

והוא כי ידוע לחכמי לב כי הנקבה של מטה מן הנקבה של מעלה סוד ה' אחרונה שבשם הכלה שבשיר השירים ונקשרת בה, לפי שנשמת הנקבה מן הנקבה כמו שאמרו בבהיר והזכר של מטה מן הזכר של מעלה סוד וא"ו שבשם ונקשר בו, לפי שנשמת הזכר מן הזכר כמו שאמרו שם, ולפי שרגלי המדה ההיא יורדות מות כידוע למקבלי האמת, הנה הנקשר בה לבדה מות מזומן לו, כי המדה גורמת, ולפי שחבקוק נקשר בנקבה שאמר לה הנביא את חובקת בן מת עד שהעיר עליו רוח חיים מלמעלה, וכמו שכתוב וישם פיו על פיו וגו' ואמרו שם במדרש לאתקשרא ליה באתר אחרא עילאה אתר דחיין אשתכחו ביה וכו', ואז שבה רוחו אליו:

ולפי שיצחק נקשר בזכר מקום החיים וכמו שכתוב שוב אשוב אליך נתקיים, ומזה יבחן האמת כי אין לשקל בשקל השכל שום דבר ממה שבא סתום בספר ההוא ובשאר הספרים שהביא זכרונם שאין לפלוסופיא חלק וזכרון בהם, שהרי הודה שלא יכילם שכל שום חוקר וחכמת הספרים ההם היא אשר קבלוה וידעוה רז"ל לא הפלוסופיא, שהרי ספר היכלות, ופרקי היכלות וספר שעור קומה, וספר הזוהר, התנאים שנאום וחברום, וספר הבהיר הוא חבור האמוראים, וזולתם הרבה מה שחברו הגאונים והרבנים הבאים אחריהם וכלם נמצאים בין החכמים, ומעולם לא נעתקו אלו הספרים ולא יצאו מן האומה לאומה אחרת, שהרי ספר יצירה מזמן אברהם אבינו נמצא בין אומתו הקדושה, וירמיהו ע"ה בזמן בית ראשון היה מתעסק בו כמו שנמצא בספר הבטחון שעשה ר' יהודה בן בתירה ע"ה, הביאו רב חמאי גאון ז"ל בספר הייחוד, וגם הביאו הקדוש קנה זלה"ה בספר הפליאה, אמר שם שירמיהו הנביא ע"ה היה מתעסק בספר יצירה בינו לבין עצמו יצאת בת קול ואמרה קנה לך חבר, הלך אצל סירא בנו ונתעסקו בספר יצירה שלש שנים, לקיים הכתוב אז נדברו יראי יי' איש אל רעהו וגו', וכבר הודה ולא בוש בזה והזכירם, ומהם שנמצאו מזמן בית שני ולא יצאו בגולה ולא הורקו מכלי קדוש וטהור אל כלי חול וטמא ולא נעתקו ולא אבדו בין האומות ובכל דור ודור החכמים השרידים מתעסקים בהם ומפרשים סודותיהם כמו שקבלו בהם, ואיך בדא מלבו הוא ורבו באמרו שאבדו החכמות הרבות הנמצאות באומתנו והספרים שחברום החכמים בשרשי החכמה ההיא אין זה מהם כי אם קריאה אל תואנות ועלילות לקיים דעותיהם הבדויים כפי השכל המחקרי בהם מרפים ידי התמימים מבקשי האמת:
```

Answer (score -2):

The answer in my opinion is that it was accepted because it had the backing of highly influential Rabbis such as the Arizal who reputedly had hasagas (spiritual powers/clairvoyance) almost like the neviim (prophets). (As evidence for these powers see the book [Shivchei Arizal](http://hebrewbooks.org/3765) for some amazing accounts.) I assume he used these powers to verify the book's authenticity.

See this footnote from http://ohr.edu/1395 :

> The Zohar was hidden for over a thousand years until R. Moshe de Leon
>   purportedly found it. Although originally there was some doubt as to
>   its authenticity, once the master Kabbalist R. Yitzchak Luria (the
>   Arizal) unequivocally attributed the Zohar to Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai,
>   this became the accepted opinion.

here's a quote from Rabbi Chaim Vital claiming that his teacher, the Arizal was in contact with Elijah the Prophet (Pri Etz Chaim).:

> אמר הצעיר והזעיר הרח"ו בראותי תשוקת החרדים אל דבר ה' ראיתי לחבר הס'
>   הזה ולהאיר עיניה' בקצת הקדמות שקבלתי ממורי זלה"ה כאשר אבאר ומהם תוכל
>   לאחוז ולקחת מעץ חיים כאשר תראה בעז"ה דברי בנוים על הקדמו' נעלמות
>   שנתגלו למורי זלה"ה ברוה"ק עפ"י אליהו ז"ל"

http://www.kab.co.il/heb/content/view/frame/29819?/heb/content/view/full/29819&main

another quote from the Ramchal in his book Adir B'Marom (intro): "I have been given permission (from upstairs) to ask and understand in any and all matters of the holy Torah even the most difficult passages in the Zohar.."

Another quote from Rabbi Chaim of Volozhin, the famed disciple of the highly influential Vilna Gaon, considered the greatest of all of Lithuanian Jewry which implies the Vilna Gaon also backed the zohar's authenticity. from here: http://www.chareidi.org/archives5763/VSH63features.htm

> Pay attention to his introduction to the commentary of his great rov
>   to the Safro Detzni'uso, his great and awesome revelations. Inter
>   alia, he relates wonderful expositions that he heard from his rov the
>   Vilna Gaon zt"l and on one occasion [his rov darshened] when [the soul of] R. Shimon
>   bar Yochai sat on his right side and the Arizal on his left

the Vilna Gaon also reputedly had great hasagas as reported [here](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5766/ZAV66features5.htm) and [here](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5766/TZR66features.htm)

Likewise Rav Yosef Karo, one of the most influential Rabbis since the Zohar's appearance cited the Zohar in his sources at the introduction to the Beit Yosef. According to this [source](http://text.rcarabbis.org/halakha-and-kabbalah-rabbi-joseph-karos-shulchan-aruch-and-magid-mesharim-by-shlomo-brody/), he also weighed the halakhic value of Zoharic prescriptions and later integrated them into the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: I'm surprised by your answer for it seems circular: imagine the Ari saying "I am the greatest master of this field of study which is true because I said so." Shouldn't we be looking for independent verification? I mean, no one who thinks the Zohar is false will believe the "prophecy" of the man they think is a charlatan. You should try and find a prophet who's prophecy isn't solely dependent on the truth of the Zohar. (As a parallel consider John Smith's being a prophet is dependent solely on the truth of the Book of Mormon. See how it's circular?)

Comment: the ari had revelations from eliyahu hanavi. likewise his talmid rav chaim vital claims he personally had these revelations in shaarei kedusha intro

Comment: How do you know that? (See how it's circular?)

Comment: @DoubleAA well, you dont get the kind of wisdom he got without divine help. Gd does not give this kind of torah wisdom to liars.

Comment: But how do you know it was Torah wisdom or even wisdom at all? (See how it's circular?)

Comment: the arizal was accepted as the gadol hador. that's enough proof of his authenticity. God doesnt grant that level of torah knowledge to liars

Comment: I agree! Of course He doesn't! The question is did the Ari really have any Torah knowledge or was it just knowledge of nonsense? (See how it's circular?)

Comment: Please edit in a source for your answer if you can.

Comment: -1 because this is silly and not a real answer. prophecy ended long ago. anyone who claims to have any kind of prophecy is truly a liar and a deceiver. if the sanhadreen would be around they would surely execute this person for blasphemy and treason.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob I said almost prophecy. and believe it not these shadows of prophecy exists even today among the gedolei hador, especially in israel

Comment: @ray yea...no there is no such thing. anyone claiming such thing are in it for something other than torah and those who believe in such thing are delusional

Comment: @DoubleAA not necessarily. If the Arizal was backed up by people not known (exclusively) for their kabbalah (say the Beis Yosef), it wouldn't be circular reasoning anymore

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Yes necessarily. However, if you want to post a different answer that the Zohar was accepted because it's authenticity was verified by the Beit Yosef, you may do so (sourced, if possible). Please be sure to include how the Beit Yosef verified it. The fact remains that this answer is quite poor and sourceless.

Comment: @DoubleAA It could be verified by the Arizal who was verified by the Beis Yosef.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin If the Beit Yosef (or anyone) independently verified the Arizal's powers of ancient-text-authoriship-verification without just relying on the Arizal's renown as a formidable master of Kabbala, then that would no longer be circular. If you can source such an event occurring AND that it is the cause of why the Zohar was accepted, that would be an answer to this question. The fact remains that this answer is quite poor and sourceless.

Comment: @DoubleAA He could (note, I don't have any evidence off the top of my head  that he did) have said that he's a huge Tzaddik, לא יאונה לצדיק כל און, etc.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin There were also "huge Tzaddik"s on the other side too though. One group of them was mistaken. I understood the whole premise here to be that the Ari's powers were somehow unique in their ability to verify the origin of the text in a uniquely (relatively) error-free way.

Comment: @DoubleAA added some sources

Comment: @ray Ya, but still no sources for your answer (which remains sourceless)

Comment: @DoubleAA i disagree with you. my point is that it had the backing of the arizal.

Comment: @ray What are you disagreeing with? Your answer is that the Zohar was accepted _because_ the Ari verified it (as you explain in your first paragraph), yet you haven't brought any source to back this up. Hence, your answer remains unsourced. I don't know what is confusing. You can go source that the Ari was greater than Moshe for all I care and that still wouldn't make your answer sourced.

Comment: I don't know why you are quoting the Vilna Gaon. Did he also have magic powers to figure out where the text came from? If not then he must be basing his belief on someone else, so how is he relevant? You make your opening paragraph sound like there were other rabbis who were quasi prophets. Can you name them?

Comment: You're aware that this footnote you cite does not say that the Zohar was accepted because the Ari checked it out with his superpowers, right? Hence, it doesn't support your claim. The footnote does not say why it was accepted then. Maybe the Ari just had a good publicist or something.

Comment: Are you claiming that the Zohar was accepted by many because the Vilna Gaon checked it out with his superpowers? That is a bizarre claim as the Zohar was pretty widespread well before the VG's time.

Comment: You really don't seem to understand the question. Sigh...

Comment: By quoting the Zohar, one does not automatically admit acceptance of it being Tanaic. Perhaps anyone quoting it thought it was a meritorious work written by a knowledgeable modern rabbi, albeit written as if from ancient times, even if not. Kind of like letting a mashal from the Dubna Magid change your life, even though you know the story is fictitious. Did the Beis Yosef ever say 'well since Zohar was written by a Tanna etc'?

Comment: @user6591 what's the alternative, santa claus? the zohar quotes R.Shimon many times. would he endorse it if it was made up lies in the name of R.Shimon

Comment: @ray Not everything is meant to be taken literally... He might endorse it because of its content instead of its mesorah. That's actually what this question is asking for, and what you keep not getting. Nu nu you don't like thinking about this. Fine.

Comment: "There were also "huge Tzaddik"s on the other side too though. One group of them was mistaken."

Maybe they were both right even tho they contradict each other. 2 times 2 is 4 but negative 2 times negative 2 is also 4. There was another question here with sources about how there is no belief in objective truth in Judaism, therefore conflicting answers can both be true even though logically it is impossible. Maybe Judaism transcends logical truths. I recall a teaching that for the sake of Israel, Hashem even transcended or subverted truth itself (maybe when Sarah laughed I dont remember)

Comment: @DoubleAA That comment above was to you, sorry I didnt tag you. But continuing, I also have questions/doubts about this answer I repeated, but I am just mentioning it for discussion. Don't think I am sure of it myself either. I believe I read that in an article of the Ari's teachings on chabad.org, but I cant find it in the usual sections, I think it was in a sub menu somewhere from an author with just a couple Ari articles. But I could be wrong about that.